# What should "cache token" be when using LRU cache in Next.js for rate limiting?

Tags: node.js, next.js, rate-limiting

I am following the Next.js rate limiting example at *[API Routes Rate Limiting Example](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/7f1d7c4fd2192d724855d9d35cf370804dd274a5/examples/api-routes-rate-limit)*, and it shows this as the base module:

```
import type { NextApiResponse } from 'next'
import LRU from 'lru-cache'

type Options = {
  uniqueTokenPerInterval?: number
  interval?: number
}

export default function rateLimit(options?: Options) {
  const tokenCache = new LRU({
    max: options?.uniqueTokenPerInterval || 500,
    ttl: options?.interval || 60000,
  })

  return {
    check: (res: NextApiResponse, limit: number, token: string) =>
      new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
        const tokenCount = (tokenCache.get(token) as number[]) || [0]
        if (tokenCount[0] === 0) {
          tokenCache.set(token, tokenCount)
        }
        tokenCount[0] += 1

        const currentUsage = tokenCount[0]
        const isRateLimited = currentUsage >= limit
        res.setHeader('X-RateLimit-Limit', limit)
        res.setHeader(
          'X-RateLimit-Remaining',
          isRateLimited ? 0 : limit - currentUsage
        )

        return isRateLimited ? reject() : resolve()
      }),
  }
}
```

And then its usage as:

```
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next'
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid'
import rateLimit from '../../utils/rate-limit'

const limiter = rateLimit({
  interval: 60 * 1000, // 60 seconds
  uniqueTokenPerInterval: 500, // Max 500 users per second
})

export default async function handler(
  _req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse
) {
  try {
    await limiter.check(res, 10, 'CACHE_TOKEN') // 10 requests per minute
    res.status(200).json({ id: uuidv4() })
  } catch {
    res.status(429).json({ error: 'Rate limit exceeded' })
  }
}
```

What is that `CACHE_TOKEN` supposed to be? In my case, I want to rate limit individual users somehow, and also rate limit globally so there's an overall limit on the traffic, in the Next.js app. My app also doesn't have user accounts; it is just a free public API which I would like to rate limit to some degree. How can I accomplish that? What technique is appropriate here?

I am currently imagining a solution where we use server-side cookies and set the cookie to a random [cuid](https://github.com/paralleldrive/cuid2) generated using a hidden secret as randomizing input. But I'm not sure where to go from that thought and what solution is most appropriate. I don't need to know the code for implementing session or cookie management; I can figure that out once I know generally the approach, so I am just looking for the high level approach to solving this problem.

*Note: I am trying to ideally implement some sort of primitive rate-limiting **without user accounts** and **without a database**. It doesn't need to be perfect, but I am wondering what the standard or ideal approach is in this situation.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cache token is the string you want to rate limit on.

> I want to rate limit individual users

Use the userID or authentication token/cookie.

> rate limit globally so there's an overall limit on the traffic

Use a static string.

> How can I accomplish that? What technique is appropriate here?

IP address-based would be good.